# Looking for completely in-memory database with certain qualities

Tags: c++, performance, fork, shared-memory, nosql

My application lets multiple users upload their own Lua scripts and I wish to add a database feature, nothing high powered, just a key/value store, or NoSQL type thing.

The application is a forking server and thus, multiple copies of each database are very wasteful.

Each time the application loads, the databases would be reloaded freshly from Lua scripts which then self destruct (no need to keep the loading data around once it's been loaded).

I'm quite familiar with MongoDB and Redis and the operations those support would be overkill for what I need. Really, an STL map would be enough except I need shared data, not a separate copy of the data per each forked instance of my process. The boost shared memory STL classes I cannot get working reliably and this server needs to be very, very reliable. (Compiling Redis into a shared module (.so) is something I would consider doing if nothing easier exists)

With that background I'm looking for an in-memory-only database with the following qualities (in order of priority, those later in the list are less essential, though still desired.

C++ source code

A key value store, NoSQL, with support for FindGreaterThanOrEqual (upper_bound) and FindLessThanOrEqual (lower_bound)

Linked in or compiled as part of the main process, not a separate process. I don't want our DevOPs having to deal with a separate server, one more thing to go wrong.

Shared access across multiple processes without using IPC, only shared memory (for speed)

Very easy to use with an API something like this (very rough idea):

Write(const char* database_name, const char* key, const char* value)

Write(const char* database_name, const int key, const int value)

string Read(const char* database_name, const char* key)

int Read(const char* database_name, int key)

No need to create the database, a write should implicitly create it if doesn't already exist and a read to a missing database just acts like a missing value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: SharedHashFile [1] comes close to your requirements. Any use? -- Simon

[1] https://github.com/simonhf/sharedhashfile

Answer (score 0):

For an embedded database, you could add bindings to any modern embedded library, such as http://sphia.org (http://sophia.systems/)

If you need a Lua language interpreter, with a built-in database, you could take a look at http://tarantool.org

Answer (score 0):

You could create a process which store the datas using STL `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` and use IPC socket with request/reply pattern for other processes to access the data (they request the datas with the key and get the datas in the reply).

I strongly advise to take a look at [ZMQ](http://zeromq.org/intro:read-the-manual) and/or [Nanomsg](http://nanomsg.org/), which are both performant, reliable library for tcp and ipc communication and have native binding in C++.